# Вывод товаров на сайте с сортировкой по удаленности от адреса покупателя?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, яндекс-карты

Всем привет.

Появилась необходимость вывести товары на сайте отсортировав их по удаленности от адреса покупателя.

Я получаю адрес доставки покупателя из БД (**Благовещенск, улица Ленина, дом 1**), теперь мне нужно вывести товары (**у которых также есть адрес склада**) сортируя их по удаленности от адреса покупателя.

Пример:

адрес покупателя - улица Ленина 1, тогда товары должны выводиться в порядке:

1. товар (с адресом улица Ленина 2)
2. товар (с адресом улица Ленина 10)
3. товар (с адресом улица Ленина 24)
4. товар (с адресом улица Кирова 140/2 к 1)
5. товар (с адресом улица Комсомольская 12А)
   .....

Вообще реально ли такое реализовать? Если да, то помогите советом, пожалуйста.
На сайте подключен Яндекс API карты.

Comment: Вкратце - ищете расстояние от адреса покупателя до адреса каждого склада. Находите наименьшее. Но тут есть несколько нюансов - искать можно как кратчайшее расстояние (т.е напрямую от точки А до точки Б), а можно по дорогам учитывая пробки и тп (т.е склад может быть в соседнем дворе, но если на машине туда ехать то через полгорода дольше по времени и расстоянию, а до другого склада в соседнем районе быстрее по времени и расстоянию). Живой пример можете посмотреть тут - https://www.infospice.ru/blog/bitrix_inside/yandeks-karty-api-ishchem-rasstoyanie-ot-mkad-do-ukazannoy-tochki/

Comment: @phpBear Здравствуйте. Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Но такой вопрос - как бы все это реализовать без показа карты? То есть я не хочу выводить карту на сайте с указаниям меток на карте. Я хочу просто отсортировать товар. Вы написали считать расстояние от адреса до адреса, может правильней будет считать по геолокации или я не прав?

Comment: Пользовательское соглашение API Яндекс Карт не позволяет работать без отображения карты на бесплатном тарифе. Небольшая карта в интерфейсе - малая плата за удобные инструменты и простоту реализации вашего сценария.

Comment: Само собой Яндекс.API считает расстояние между двух по гео-координат. Просто Вы озвучили "адрес" я про него и писал. В принципе Вы можете "на лету" получать гео-координаты каждого из адресов и уже их передавать с соответствующий метод API. Если же Вы хотите без Яндекс.Карт это делать - у Вас только один выход - `postgresql` + `PostGIS` (https://postgis.net/)

Comment: @phpBear Спасибо, Вы направили меня в правильную сторону. Можете написать ответом и я отмечу его решением.

Comment: Не за плюсики работаем :) Помог - и слава богу. Простого "спасибо" мне достаточно :)

Comment: @phpBear, спасибо большое